# Extensible Local HTTP Server with Framework in Python

Tags: python, localhost, web-frameworks, httpserver

I'm trying to build a desktop application using Python. To make it able to be used on as many platforms as possible, I think web UI may be a good choice. This boils down to the problem of making a local HTTP server first. I did some survey and found that people are mainly talking about BaseHTTPServer and SimpleHTTPServer. For prototyping, subclassing them may suffice.

Besides pure prototyping, I also want to leave some room for extension to real service. That is, once mature, I'd like to move the codes to a real dedicated HTTP server, so that end users only need a browser to use it.

I say "extensible" in the following sense:

- The code modification is as minimum as possible in the migration process.
- I will focus on algorithm in the prototyping stage. I also want to leave some room for future front end designer.

It looks WSGI + Django is a widely mentioned combination. After some search, what I found is using WSGI in apache or nginx. Is it possible to use self-contained modules? i.e. wsgiref + Django, so that I can start everything just from one entry script. I don't want to bother potential first adopters by asking them install apache and configure it. It will be very good if you have sample codes or pointers for further reading.

I'm new to Python and web programming in Python. Thanks for your help. I just try to make sure I'm on the right track. My underlying algorithms is implemented in Python 2.7. So the UI solution had better also be in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may want is `Bottle`. It is a web framework that only needs the standard library to be installed. It also has compatibility with many other production servers, as well as shipping with it's own development server. And if that isn't good enough, it is all in a *single file*, and has support with many different templating languages, as well as it's own built in templating language.

Check it out here: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

Comment: I think the **single file** aspect is very attractive for me. I can just put the file under my project tree (with proper license statements). I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned bottle is a good choice, I personally like Flask, which if I recall correctly is what bottle is based off of. Anyways there are three things that really make Flask a joy to use.

- [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/) - essentially an application architecture
- [Flask-Sijax](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Sijax/) - allows for comet technology
- [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) - an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing

there are a lot of other plugins, including one for an admin interface that I haven't tried out yet but it looks promising, and it works with Python 2.7

Comment: Here's a pretty good discussion on bottle.py vs Flask. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941145/python-flask-vs-bottle

Comment: The pointers therein are very useful. I also watched the Richard's video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYjPIMe0BhA